# logcat filtering and number of lines

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

This issue has been puzzeling me and I hope to find an answer from you.

I am trying to display the last 100 occurances(or lines) of logs that have my class xx tag and of level Info

this is done using

Adb logcat -t 100 -v long xx:I *:s

I am getting only last 12 or so occurances of xx:I not 100.

could it be that logcat is readig last 100 lines of logs and filtering them based on my criteria? Shouldnt it display last 100 tagged lines?

Comment: Comon, no answer yet????

Comment: Why is the last 100 lines required. Why not just remove this filter. Personally I use the eclipse boxes to filter logcat. Not some string of settings. Is this console?

Comment: You are correct, however the reason I want the last 100 lines is because I am sending the log using ACRA in case a crash happens in production. They recommend to use number less than 200 (and I thought 200 would mean 200 of filtered lines not total 200 before filtering)

Answer (score 1):

Write `adb logcat -t 100 -v long xx:I`, without `*:s`.